# REST not working on published version, works locally

Tags: c#, azure, rest, linq

I always had a working version in Azure but somehow it does not work anymore, I copied the database and I created new connections. When I run in localhost all works fine, however when I publish it does not work anymore, unless I delete the analytics section of the REST

this is what I got:

```
    // GET PROGRAM (IF EXIST)
    [Route("api/Program/{ProgramCode}/{id_user}/{id_client}")]
    public object GetProgramSettingsFromFile(string ProgramCode, string id_user, int id_client)
    {

        AnalyticsUser newEntry = new AnalyticsUser
        {
            id_user = id_user,
            ProgramCode = ProgramCode,
            DateTime = DateTime.Now,
            id_client = id_client
        };
        db.AnalyticsUsers.Add(newEntry);
        db.SaveChanges();

        string secondPart = "api/program/" + ProgramCode + ".json";

        var allText = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(uriPath + secondPart);
        object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

the above works fine in local host, but when published it does not work. Error 500 internal server error. So when i escape the analytics section like this:

```
    // GET PROGRAM (IF EXIST)
    [Route("api/Program/{ProgramCode}/{id_user}/{id_client}")]
    public object GetProgramSettingsFromFile(string ProgramCode, string id_user, int id_client)
    {

        //AnalyticsUser newEntry = new AnalyticsUser
        //{
        //    id_user = id_user,
        //    ProgramCode = ProgramCode,
        //    DateTime = DateTime.Now,
        //    id_client = id_client
        //};
        //db.AnalyticsUsers.Add(newEntry);
        //db.SaveChanges();

        string secondPart = "api/program/" + ProgramCode + ".json";

        var allText = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(uriPath + secondPart);
        object jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(allText);

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

it works fine on localhost and on published. So what is going in here? I can't seem to replicate the error locally since it all works fine. Is there any idea?

Comment: Is your db initialized? Issue is not with rest call but saving data to your db. Check connectionString and see if it set up correctly and have access to the db server

Comment: 500 means that you have exception, probably with connection string.

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#access-log-files

Answer (score 1):

alright it was something in the Azure SQL server that was producing the error. For other that might encounter the same problem, cause localhost connecting to the database was working fine, also using the webconfig connection string, means that something is blocking it when published.

In Azure SQL Database Firewall settings there is a switch:

Allow Azure services and resources to access this server

This one had to be to yes (was on No)

Now it's working fine (the SAVE analytics setting is an internal connection) that is why ta was working without fine but with it got blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can run normally locally, you can debug or find the ConnectionString in the project (`appconfig.json` or `web.config` file).

Check your ConnectionString and replace the SQL Server connection string in the production environment.

You can [configure the strings of the production environment in the configuration file or on the portal](http://You%20can%20configure%20the%20strings%20of%20the%20production%20environment%20in%20the%20configuration%20file%20or%20on%20the%20portal.).

**Tips：**

1. If you don't have azure sql server, as long as the sql server that can be accessed on the public network is also possible.
2. Note that the table structure and stored procedures or functions of the database in the production environment must be consistent.